# How to access data from onesignal additional data object in cordova ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, onesignal

I want to access data i have assigned to the data variable of feilds array to be sent in onesignal message.

```
      function sendMessage($received)
     {
         $content = array(
        "en" => 'Current Data'
      );


        $data = $received;

        $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        'included_segments' => array('All'),
        'contents' => $content,
        'data' => $data,   // => This is the data i want to access on 
       client side.
        );

      $response['feilds'] = $fields;

     $fields = json_encode($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
  "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
   application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization:Basic 
    Nzg0YmM2NzUtZWYyMC00NDZmLWE1ODItZDExZTU3OTXXXXXX'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response['resp'] = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

I need help that how i can access the data variable there on client side in ionic app.
Below is what i am trying.

```
      this.oneSignal.startInit('XXXXXXX-32ae-4025-b26b- 
      XXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXX');


      this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((jsonData) => {

        if(jsonData.payload.additionalData)
        {
          this.myService.NotirefreshData(jsonData.payload.additionalData);
          let ten =  JSON.stringify(jsonData.payload.additionalData);
          this.storage.set('current',ten);
          this.presentAlert('From Server',ten);
          this.storage.get('past').then((pri) => {
            this.presentAlert('From Storage',JSON.parse(pri));
          });
        }
```

How should be the below statement to access the data variable to array feild received from server?

(jsonData.payload.additionalData.??????????????)

I have tried

(jsonData.payload.additionalData.feilds)

(jsonData.payload.additionalData.current) // as current is the name of an array

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that `subscribe()` call. Simply pass in the handler into the function.

```
window.plugins.OneSignal
  .startInit("YOUR_APP_ID")
  .handleNotificationReceived(function(notificationData) {
    alert("Notification Data Received:\n" + JSON.stringify(notificationData));
    console.log('Notification Data Received: ' + JSON.stringify(notificationData));
  })
  .endInit();
```

Comment: jsonData.payload.additionalData.original worked for me. Original was the array meaningful to me. Thank you